# How to code sign IPA on Linux

Tags: xcode, unix, ipa, sign

#### Question

How would one sign an `IPA` using a valid `certificate` from Apple on a different `unix` system?

I know that normally the `XCode` additional *command line tools* can provide this functionality.
Are there any alternative toolchains to sign an `IPA` on other unix distros?

#### Context

I have a finished IPA that I want to ship for some clients for publication. I don't think that they have a Mac at their disposal but they do have some `linux` that could potentially do the job.

Comment: I haven't had any success with it. I remember finding some "unofficial" methods using private APIs. The problem with that is it might break at any moment if apple changes things; which they often do. You could try a CI server running on OSX for this task, otherwise the risk/complexity of figuring out how to do it on linux is not worth it in my opinion.